# Failed to create group xxx. Dynamic membership rule validation error: Invalid value

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft365

I want to creat a dynamic group that get all users that has MICROSOFT 365 BUSINESS PREMIUM

Syntax

```
(user.accountEnabled -eq true) and (user.assignedPlans -eq SPB)
```

The string is base on this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/enterprise-users/licensing-service-plan-reference)

MICROSOFT 365 BUSINESS PREMIUM = SPB

Above give me an error saying

```
Failed to create group
Failed to create group Business Premium Users. Dynamic membership rule validation error: Invalid value.
```

PS. I also tried the `guId`. gives the same error

Comment: Hi did you check my answer? Anything else is unclear?

Comment: @AllenWu thank you and I appreciate the detailed explanation. ill accept your answer, but I'm open to other solutions as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, **SPB** (MICROSOFT 365 BUSINESS PREMIUM) is license rather than plan. So you should look into `user.assignedLicenses` rather than `user.assignedPlans`.

Secondly, for [Multi-value properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/enterprise-users/groups-dynamic-membership#multi-value-properties), we should use `-any` operator, for example:

```
user.assignedPlans -any (assignedPlan.servicePlanId -eq "efb87545-963c-4e0d-99df-69c6916d9eb0")
```

So combining the above two points, it should be written like this (please note that `cbdc14ab-d96c-4c30-b9f4-6ada7cdc1d46` is the GUID of MICROSOFT 365 BUSINESS PREMIUM):

```
user.assignedLicenses -any (assignedLicense.skuId -eq "cbdc14ab-d96c-4c30-b9f4-6ada7cdc1d46")
```

Unfortunately, `assignedLicenses` property is not listed in this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/enterprise-users/groups-dynamic-membership). And based on my test, it will show `Dynamic membership rule validation error: Invalid object type.`

I finally found a [user voice post](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169401-azure-active-directory/suggestions/35803351-allow-assignedlicenses-as-a-supported-property-for) which mentions the same thing. You can vote it up if you need this feature.